# java out of memory Exception (jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, heap-memory

I am trying to read serialized objects from mysql database in a loop and perform some operations on it in java.
I have written the following function for returning me the object from ResultSet the object.

```
public static MyObj deSerializeCacheTagInfo(ResultSet res
    ) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
{
    byte[] buf = res.getBytes(3);
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    if (buf != null)
        objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
    MyObj info = (MyObj)objectIn.readObject();
    return info;
}
```

When I run this code, it gives me an out of memory exception.
I searched around a bit and realized it could be because result set is large and it is kept in memory, so I tried fetching some 50 rows at a time.

But that doesn't seem to help either.

On profiling with visualvm, it reports that all the space is being hogged by `byte[] objects`.
But I am not entirely sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you use [`getBinaryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(int)) instead of [`getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(int))?

Comment: How large is the data blob coming out of the database?

Comment: Close the ResultSet after byte[] buf = res.getBytes(3);

Comment: the size of the blob is between 2-3 MB. However in one query I fetch only 100 rows and the memory used up by the code is over 2 GB when it goes out of memory.

Comment: @Munesh that might be it. Will try and get back.

Comment: @Munesh that was the reason. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `objectIn.close();` before returning, it may help

Comment: I had high hopes after realizing I had missed out on closing the stream, but it doesn't seem to help. Any other ideas?

Comment: This was required but in my case the reason was I wasn't closing the resultset after I had extracted all rows and simply reusing it again, which led to memory leak, as Munesh pointed out in the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

By default MySQL JDBC driver fetches *the complete ResultSet* into memory.

You can change this to a streamed fetch with something like this:

```
Statement st = connIn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. After this any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the heap space by using the option `-mx256m` for 256mb heap space or `-mx512m` for 512mb and so on.

Search for increasing heap space by setting VM arguments on net.

this might help

[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Comment: That there is a memory leak was evident. I wanted ideas on where it could be, which Munesh answered in comments above.